# Android: Using putextras() is necessary Intent Service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, intentservice

I am using IntentService in my application. I want to know that, Is this Necessary to putExtras() before calling to startService(intentService) Method. Or can i call the startService(intentService) without providing data to intent. I want to know the reason behind this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it is not, you can use extra if you want to pass serialized or parcelable data through intent to your service. Then get them in onStartCommand() method

Answer (score 1):

```
Is this Necessary to putExtras() before calling to startService(intentService)??
```

Answer is No.

`putExtras()` is used to pass the data between `Activitys` and `Services`.if you want send some data to Service then Use `putExtras()`

The same intent here in `IntenetService` will received `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` get the data from the intent using `getExtras()` method

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not needed. If you want to pass some values to the activity which is started by Intent then only you need to use **putExtras()**. Otherwise use can start activity using **startActivity(intent)** without implementing **putExtras()**